# Modify layers in Tensorflow, Keras or PyTorch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I want to modify output of every layer in tensorFlow before passing to next layer in this format for standard deep neural network (Not CNN necessarily):

Say this is Pseudocode of layers during forward propagation prior to any modification, and X is input feature matrix:

```
Prior Modification:
Step 0: l0 = X
Step 1: l1 = nonlin(np.dot(l0,syn0)) and
Step 2: l2 = nonlin(np.dot(l1,syn1))
Step 3: get error, back propagate and modify weights syn0 and syn1.
```

So outputs of each layer are in l1 and l2, where nonlin is the sigmoid activation function (or someother like ReLU). Syn0 and Syn1 are the corresponding weights which are initially randomized and then modified later by back-propagation using loss function like cross-entropy or l2 error etc. So far so good- all looks standard. Ofcourse, tensorflow allows for bias term etc in the standard sense along with epochs, batches, learning rate, variations of drop-out/regularization and other fancy features etc.

What i instead want to do is the following modification to that pseudo-code in forward propagation steps:

```
 After Modification:
    l0 = M0 %*% X
    l1 = nonlin(np.dot(M1 %*% l0, syn0)) and
    l2 = nonlin(np.dot(M2 %*% l1, syn1))
    get error, back propagate and modify weights syn0 and syn1.
```

If you notice I updated l0, l1 and l2 with corresponding matrix multiplication (denoted by %*%) with matrices M0, M1, M2 respectively, which we can refer to in this pseudo-code as YoYoMats. All YoYoMats are square and symmetric and provided before hand along with dataset X and response or label column.

how can this be implemented in Keras or TensorFlow? Ideally in RKeras or RtensorFlow. If not Python version or Pytorch etc is okay too! I can implement this change by implementing vanilla NN from scratch in Python, but I want to do it in TensorFlow or Keras to use this change with all of the other supercool features these matured tools give and I am not skilled to create TensorFlow of my own kind from scratch :). hence, this question of implementing this within TensorFlow or Keras code etc.

Note as you see the modification is easy till layer l1 because the modified version is same as:

```
After Modification:
        l0 = M1 %*% M0 %*% X
        l1 = nonlin(np.dot(l0, syn0)) and
        l2 = nonlin(np.dot(M2 %*% l1, syn1))
        get error, back propagate and modify weights syn0 and syn1.
```

So, its easy to just modify l0 as follows and use it in l1 the usual way. Nothing changes till here. So simple. The tricky part is only from layer l2 and onwards if we had more layers in implementing the multiplication with M2 or say M3, M4 etc. Do I need to modify output of tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected to get this done? If so how? If not, alternate way? Caveat-if the above pseudocode was modified for training. I need prediction function modified with corresponding YoYoMats as well for testing/out-of-sample prediction purposes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following (assuming you have the same number of yoyos as samples)

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Activation

dataInput = Input(shapeOfOneDataSample)
M0 = Input(shapeOfOneYoyoForLayer1)
M1 = Input(shapeOfOneYoyoForLayer2)
M2 = Input(shapeOfOneYoyoForLayer3)

#l0
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.batch_dot(x[0], x[1]))([M0, dataInput])

#l1
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.batch_dot(x[0], x[1]))([M1, out])
out = Dense(someUnits, activation='simgoid')(out)

#l2
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.batch_dot(x[0], x[1]))([M2, out])
out = Dense(someOtherUnits)(out)
out = Activation('sigmoid')(out) 

model = Model(inputs=[dataInput, M0, M1, M2], outputs = out)
```

Compile this model with a chosen optimizer and loss function:

```
from keras.optimizers import <someOptimizerIfYouNeed>
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='mse') #just for instance
```

Fit this model passing the data and the yoyos as input:

```
model.fit([numpyData, numpyM0s, numpyM1s, numpyM2s], expectedOutputs, .....)
```

---

Warning: the `batch_dot` function may work in strange ways, I recommend that you inspect it thoroughly. (Or you can use some of the `tf` matrix multiplications if you're used to them).

Comment: what do you mean same number of yoyomats as samples? you meant layers instead of samples or something else wrt dimension? somethings missing-plz clarify

Comment: I meant samples (actually one array per layer, each array with `batch_size` yoyoMats).. It sounded like that by your question. If it's not, please detail.